# How to echo a topic if not using ROS?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
Somehow despite being a ROS user for a couple of years, I never realised gazebo has its own publisher / subscriber system that works separately from ROS! I am guessing this somehow works with plugins, however is there an equivalent of

rostopic list
rostopic echo

That can be run from the command line to simply monitor the output from the plugins? Or does this need to be added as a cout statement?

Additionally, are the nodes you ca initialize different from ROS nodes? I have read the tutorials but still feel unclear,

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22395/how-to-echo-a-topic-if-not-using-ros?/) by [Wireline](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/10175/wireline/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

You can use the `gz` command for doing it. There are nice things you can do using `gz`. Give a try and type `gz` on your terminal and it will appear the help message with all your options.

For your question in specific, using `gz topic --echo <topic>`  will show the topic messages. For see all running topics, you can run `gz topic --list`

---

Originally posted by [rasecg3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7335/rasecg3/) with karma: 62 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2